# Assigning a command to an array in shell script isn't working?

Tags: shell-script, array

When I run run the command in the terminal it assigns the array.

```
$ FILES=($(ls ~/Desktop/TEST/))
$ echo ${FILES[@]}
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

But as soon as I close the terminal and run it in a shell script I get a blank line?

```
$ ./TEST.txt 
$ echo ${FILES[@]}

$
```

I have tested it with `echo $?` and it returns true/`0`.

Unsure as to what is happening?

Comment: would you post the complete bash script? thx

Comment: `#Unzip file. `
`#unzip ~/Desktop/TEST.zip`
` `
`FILES=($(ls ~/Desktop/TEST/))`
`## Remove -, _, and ‘ ‘ from the name of files`
`#for i in “${FILES[@]}” ; do`
`# sed "s/[_ ]//g" $i`
`#done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `echo` command is not part of the script. The script is performed in a subshell en when the script ends the `FILES` variable is not available anymore. To make the `FILES` variable available to the current shell use:

```
$ source ./TEST.txt
$ echo ${FILES[@]}
```